# How to set random 3 unit "ships" in a multi dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, text, multidimensional-array

Im making a text based battleship game to practice programming in Java (I'm still quite new, so bear with me :S)
The game has a 7x7 grid system made using a multidimensional array of chars ('-').
When the user has a hit, it changes one of those '-' into an 'x'. The user provides coordinates such as A1, B5, etc, and the program converts it into numbers from 0-6 that the array can read.

Now I have this method, setPlayerShips in my Player class thats supposed to set different x and y coordinates in arrays called playerShip1, playerShip2, and playerShip3. The first element in the array is the x coordinate of the first point for the ship, the second element is the y coordinate. The third is the x coordinate of the second point, fourth is for the y coordinate, and so on. The ships can be either vertical or horizontal (not slanted) and again, are 3 units in length.
When I run the program, I have noticed that this method isn't working properly at all (it's not settings the ships 3 units in length, and not in proper places), so can you guys please take a look at this method and help me figure out whats wrong with it?
--note that the end of the method isnt the real end, it continues with the same code twice more for the two other ships

```
//set player ships coordinates, can be numbers from 0-6
  public static void setPlayerShips(){
    //first two coordinates are completely random(from 0-6)
    playerShip1[0]=(int)(Math.random()*7);
    playerShip1[1]=(int)(Math.random()*7);
    //next coordinates have to be next to this point, but can be in any direction
    do{
      playerShip1[2]=(int)(Math.random()*7);
    }while((Math.abs(playerShip1[2]-playerShip1[0]))>1);//x coordinate has to be either 1 away from or on the same as the first
    //if x coordinates are the same, y has to be 1 more than first y (unless first y is 5 - then make it 1 less than first y or else ship wont fit)
    if(playerShip1[0]==playerShip1[2] && playerShip1[1]>=5){
      playerShip1[3]=playerShip1[1]+1;
    }else if(playerShip1[0]==playerShip1[2] && playerShip1[1]>=5){
      playerShip1[3]=playerShip1[1]-1;
    }
    //if, both x's are the same, third x must be as well
    if(playerShip1[0]==playerShip1[2]){
      playerShip1[4]=playerShip1[0];
    }else if(playerShip1[0]==0){//else, if they aren't equal and the first x is 0 - add the last to the end after the second so it fits
      playerShip1[4]=playerShip1[2]+1;
    }else{//else, add it before the first x
      playerShip1[4]=playerShip1[0]-1;
    }
    //if both y coordinates equal eachother , third must be equal as well
    if(playerShip1[1]==playerShip1[3]){
      playerShip1[5]=playerShip1[1];
    }else if(playerShip1[3]==6){//else if second y coordinate is 6 and they are not all equal, next must come before first or it wont fit
      playerShip1[5]=playerShip1[1]-1;
    }else if(playerShip1[1]==0){//else if first y coordinate is 1, next must come after second y coordinate or it wont fit
      playerShip1[5]=playerShip1[3]+1;
    }
```

Thanks in advance - sorry if this is a noob question !

Comment: the way to solve these problems is to work out what the values should be by hand and debug through your code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should review your « ship description » making a related class to store its location.

Then, your algorithm does not look friendly. I propose you an other:

1. Pick a point: `(x, y)` on your grid (use `Math.random() * 7`),
2. Pick a direction: *top =* `0`, *left =* `1`, *bottom =* `2` or *right =* `3` (use `Math.random() * 4`),
3. Compute ship points: if *right*, `x` values are the same and `y` are `y`, `y + 1` and `y + 2` for exemple. If top, `x` values are `x`, `x - 1`, `x - 2` and `y` values are `y`.

Before 3) you could check in ships fit in the grid according to original position and direction (eg (`x = 3` and `y = 1` with direction = *top* will not fit (`y` values are `1`, `0` and `-1`)). If it does not fit, simply pick new point and direction.

I hope it will help you!